# Multiple independent $http requests in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular application I have several controllers/providers that each make their own requests to fetch data. However some of the requests take some time to perform, during which all other http requests seems to hang until the long running requests finishes. Is there any way to work around this, or is this not even intended? My update functions looks like this:

```
    $scope.updateData = function () {
        $http.post($scope.callbackUrl).success(function (data) {
            $scope.items = data;
            $timeout($scope.updateData, $scope.updateInterval);
        }).error(function () {
            $timeout($scope.updateData, $scope.updateInterval);
        });
    };
```

What happens is this:

```
Slow request starts
Fast request starts
Fast request starts
.... and so on until slow request ends 10s later
Slow request ends
Fast request ends
Fast request ends
```

Comment: what's the need for the $timeout in this situation?

Comment: I don't think it's `$http`'s fault.  I have an app that has 6 connections going at once and don't seem to have the same problem.  Could you show more code?  Where do you have multiple calls happening?  What's in the back-end?  For MVC development I've found that session gets locked sometimes when doing a request so if you data is coming from services that use session, maybe only one can process at a time?

Comment: I think as well that the problem is probably with your back-end.

Comment: The $timeout is used to not spam requests. On the backend I am currently using 1 slow request that indeed uses a session object. However the other 2 fast requests are not using the session at all, they are just returning mock data in the form of Json(new List<DataType>() { ... }. That might be the problem however since the session object is made for regular application and uses threads and stuff. Yes, that's really bad, but it was given by the customer. +1 for the thought however Jason.

Comment: This was not the reason either, I cleared the session from objects completely, and just put a Thread.Sleep(..) and returned mock data from the slow request as well, and I still got the same behavior.